# Raspberry pi 3 vs Jetson TK1 for ROS

Tags: ros, cuda, jetson-tk1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have ROS running on a number of Rasp' Pi's - and I was looking at the much more expensive nVidia Jetson TK1...then I started thinking relative to a RPi 3 was am I really going to benefit from (In the base case at least)?

I've found a few comparisons (http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=raspberry-pi-3&num=1)  but I wondered if anyone had any other info/actually using it on ROS - what is like?

This is just looking at the CPU side - is there anything ROS optimised to take advantage of the GPUs for example (Cuda et al)

I know Autonomous are selling the TK1 with the Kobuki base (http://www.cnx-software.com/2016/01/25/autonomous-deep-learning-robot-features-nvidia-jetson-tk1-board-a-3d-camera-and-more/).

Of course there is always the TX1 $£$

Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250413/raspberry-pi-3-vs-jetson-tk1-for-ros/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2016-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The base packages ship pretty generic code, which means most packages aren't going to take advantage of the Cuda support on the TK1. Even getting Nvidia's optimized version of OpenCV to work with ROS can be a bit challenging.

Neither board will run Rviz well. (The TK1 can run Rviz, but I don't recommend it)

The CPU cores in the TK1 are very roughly on par with the Pi3 (I haven't run thorough comparison benchmarks)

The Pi3 has a fully removable disk (SD card), so flashing it, recovering it, and making backups is a lot easier than the TK1, which uses non-removable storage.

The Pi3 has more USB ports and the GPIO probably has better support.

The TK1 has CUDA, a USB3 port and mini-PCIe slot.

In general, I'd recommend that you get the Pi3 unless you really need the features that are available on the TK1.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-12-20**:
@ahendrix - thanks - I was thinking the Pi3 would be the better bet